# Proverb for "Happiness comes only through hard work"

Tags: proverbs, proverb-requests

Is there a common English proverb, or maxim which means happiness won't come unless you work hard?

Looking online for idioms about happiness, I found several resources but they only speak about the degree of happiness; e.g. *on cloud nine*, *jump for joy*, and  *over the moon*. Whereas the  website [Special Dictionary](http://www.special-dictionary.com/proverbs/keywords/happiness/) has a list of proverbs about happiness, they are not English ones. The closest I found was Finnish.

- *Happiness does not come from happiness itself, but from the journey towards achieving it.*

I have come up with three versions, but are they idiomatic?

> 1. Happiness only comes through hard work.
> 2. You'll never be happy unless you work hard.
> 3. You will not get happiness without doing hard work.

Is there a well-known proverb I can use instead?

Comment: If you have the equivalent proverb in your native language, it's always a good idea to add that in your question. I also think the question, as it now stands, lacks detail. Why are you looking for a proverb? Can you explain the situation that requires the need for one? Would you be equally happy with an idiom, or idiomatic  phrase?

Comment: Take a look at this person's question. If you can achieve the same kind of detail, people on EL&U will look more favourably on it  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177634/are-there-any-english-sayings-equivalent-to-the-japanese-proverb-go-to-bed-ear

Comment: Relevant quotes are: “Happiness is not in the mere possession of money; it lies in the joy of achievement, in the thrill of creative effort.” _
Franklin D. Roosevelt // “Action may not always bring happiness; but there is no happiness without action.” _ Benjamin Disraeli // “Everyone wants to live on top of the mountain, but all the happiness and growth occurs while you’re climbing it.” _ Andy Rooney. // “The grass is always greener where you water it.” [anonymous] [[Positivity Blog](http://www.positivityblog.com/index.php/2013/08/20/happiness-quotes/)] But they're hardly of proverb status.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you very much for your edition, my native language is **Nepali** and I searched for the proverb in http://silentcsanj.blogspot.co.ke/2015/04/english-nepali-ukhan-proverbs.html?m=1 and found **No pains, no gains— dukha nagari sukha painna** . Is it commonly used proverb for what I'm searching for ?

Comment: I hope for your further edition of my question.

Comment: I think you should post the saying *no pains, no gains*, I've checked and it has a much older history than I originally thought.

Comment: Ok I'm going to post it

Answer (score 3):

My partner studied Latin in high school and offers this:

> Per aspera ad astra

I did not care for any of the English translations I found.  However, in es.wikipedia.org, [I found](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per_aspera_ad_astra) a nice Spanish version, *A través del esfuerzo, el triunfo*, which I will translate as

> Through effort comes triumph.

If you want to say this after a long, satisfying meeting of your study group, for example, I would recommend sharing it with both the Latin and the English versions, e.g.

> "There is a Latin proverb that goes *Per aspera ad astra*, which means, 'Through effort comes triumph.' "